# Facebook Graph API - access without logging in multiple times

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a system where users can log in a see stats of Facebook pages I administer.

I don't want the users to have to log in each time they visit the site, and more importantly they will only be able to see the stats for all pages if it was my account that was logged in.

Is it common practise to log in with my account, get an extended access token and store in a database so future users don't need to keep logging in via Facebook to see the stats?

Comment: Yes, that's what the token is made for. Also, you will probably need some sort of cookie storage, so you know which token belongs to which user, when they return to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the "manage_pages" extended permission. If your application received this permission via an User Access Token, it could call

```
/me/accounts
```

with this Access Token and receive the Page Access Tokens for all Pages this User administers. With these you could access the Page insights of the respective Page.